# Clustering strings into similarity groups

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, cluster-computing

I'm trying to cluster strings in order to have clusters of similar strings, for example, `"clavier"` and `"clvier"` should appear in the same cluster.

I'm trying [this code](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158090/157545) like:

```
final_list2 = np.asarray(final_list2) 

lev_similarity =-1* np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in final_list2] for w2 in final_list2])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5,convergence_iter=15, max_iter=200)
affprop=affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
   
    exemplar = final_list2[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(final_list2[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print (exemplar, cluster_str)
```

But I'm not getting any cluster centers.

```
print(affprop.cluster_centers_indices_)
```

shows `[]`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or, any suggestions that could give me better results?

Answer (score 0):

```
final_list2 = "clavier clvier clavier clvier apple appl apple appl".split(" ")
final_list2 = np.asarray(final_list2) #So that indexing with a list will work

lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in final_list2] for w2 in final_list2])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop=affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
```

outputs

```
[1 7]
```

for me.

Comment: I'm getting this warning
ConvergenceWarning: Affinity propagation did not converge, this model will not have any cluster centers. "will not have any cluster centers.", ConvergenceWarning)
 i think it's a version problem i found this link explaining the issue https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17657  but didn't know how to fix it still

Comment: @oumaimal Aren't you using the latest one?

Comment: I created a new environment where I’m using the 21.3 version and it Worked perfectly Thank you very much for your help

Comment: The failure to converge can happen if you have a lot of similar distances. You can perturb the input a little if you don't care about non-deterministic clusters by adding noise: `lev_similarity += np.random.normal(0, 0.01, lev_similarity.shape)`